# Ember-js Onclick function not work

Tags: ember.js, popover, bootstrap-4

Im used `Bootstrap v4-alpha`  Im added pop over its working, but i need to add `popover-content` for the `on click` function its not fire in `Ember-js`,
how to put  onclick function in emebr-js
 this is im used onlick event

```
<li class="list-group-item" onclick={{action `'event'}}>Airport Pickup</li>
```

**This is my code sample**
**add-newbooking.hbs**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" title="Bill Category">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder=""></a>
      </div>

<title>Bootstrap Example</title>

<!-- loaded popover content -->
<div id="popover-content" style="display: none">
  <ul class="list-group custom-popover">
    <li class="list-group-item" onclick={{action 'event'}}>Airport Pickup</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" >Food and Beverage</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Yoga Class</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  });
});</script>
```

**add-newbooking.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    event: function () {
      console.log("ppessssssss")
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: [read guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guides have [a whole section on this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/templates/actions/)

```
<li class="list-group-item" {{action 'event'}}>Airport Pickup</li>
```

You could be better off adding a link or button inside the list item though so that the button is focusable etc

Answer (score 0):

adding onclick and action on an element will add both events i.e. DOM events as well as ember events. so always remember to add any one of the events (preferably ember).